# Python Selenium unable to click on button (not inside iframe)

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, xpath

There's a button on the webpage that looks like this:

```
<button class="WAXG WEXG WKKH WOWG WPO" tabindex="0" data-automation-activebutton="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" data-automation-id="wd-ActiveList-addButton" role="button" data-automation-button-type="AUXILIARY" title="Add" type="button"><span class="WFXG WBXG"></span><span class="WCXG" title="Add">Add</span></button>
```

I use the following code to click on the button:

```
xpath = "//button[@data-automation-id='wd-ActiveList-addButton']"
add = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
add.click()
```

It always results in the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I have tried using different ways to find the element and click, but always get the same error. The button is not inside an iframe. Moreover, I'm able to access/click on all elements around the button. As the error message is empty, I'm clueless as to why this happens.

EDIT

Here's some surrounding code from the inspector:

```
<div class="WF-M WFN WOYM WEYM" id="wd-SectionView-NO_METADATA_ID">
    <div class="WH-M">
        <div class="WOO WFN" data-automation-id="activeList" id="wd-ActiveList-  6$87772">
            <div class="WHP">
            </div>
            <button class="WAXG WEXG WKKH WOWG WPO" tabindex="0" data-automation-activebutton="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" data-automation-id="wd-ActiveList-addButton" role="button" data-automation-button-type="AUXILIARY" title="Add" type="button">
                <span class="WFXG WBXG"></span>
                <span class="WCXG" title="Add">Add</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if you try clicking the span instead of the button? `xpath = "//span[@title='Add']"`? There is a chance the button isn't actually visible or has a size of 0. Not very likely given the `html` here, but possible. You could also try using devtools or firepath to see what element is highlighted when you put your mouse over the button, as it could actually be an element that contains the button.

Comment: Check if this is the only element with specified selector `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@data-automation-id='wd-ActiveList-addButton']")))`. There might be same hidden button

Comment: @mrfreester I still get the same error using `xpath = "//span[@title='Add']"`. Firepath generated the following xpath for the button when I clicked on it: `.//*[@id='wd-ActiveList-6$87772']/button`.

Comment: @Andersson I tried that and it prints 0. I tried different identifiers, still 0.

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: @Andersson I'm sorry, but it's not a public page.

Comment: Then you should double-check that it's really not located inside an `iframe`. Check all ancestor elements

Comment: Can you post some more of the surrounding `html`? Also, it looks like you have an extra set of `()` here `((By.XPATH, xpath))`, although this might just be my unfamiliarity with how the `python` bindings work, but that could be causing a problem.

Comment: @Andersson I searched the inspector to see if there were any iframes, but there were none. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Could you share little more `HTML`? including those elements you said you can click

Comment: @Andersson I added a link to the entire html from the inspector and the other element I'm able to click. I did find find a couple of <iframe> elements, but the they are at the very end of the document. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @mrfreester It does need the extra set of `()`. Please find the `html` in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've already assumed in comments there are two buttons on page that can be found by attribute `data-auto‌​mation-id='wd-Active‌​List-addButton'`: the first is hidden. That's why your expectation to wait until it become visible always returns `False`

You might need to use below code:

```
xpath = "(//button[@data-automation-id='wd-ActiveList-addButton'])[2]"
add = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
add.click()
```

It should allow you to click visible `"Add"` button